# How to get RTC work item epic id and filed against data using feature Id

Tags: java, api, rtc

I have got the work item data using below code

```
IWorkItem workItem = workItemClient.findWorkItemById(id, IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE, monitor);
List<IWorkItemHandle> workItemHandle = 
workItemClient.findWorkItemsById(workItemIds, monitor);
```

But there I am not able to find any attributes like filed against and planned for. Please help how I could get this data.